# CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) origin validation failure

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

Recently i did a site for a client. After receiving it the client sent the site for acunetix security check, which brought back this alert.

----acunetix alert---
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Any origin is accepted (arbitrary Origin header values are reflected in Access-Control-
Allow-Origin response headers). For the WordPress /wp-json/ endpoint, this may be

the intended behavior and requires manual review. For further information, please
refer to the WordPress REST API Handbook linked in the "References" section below.`
--- the end of acunetix alert ---

i finally found where this is located - in rest-api.php

```
function rest_send_cors_headers( $value ) {
    $origin = get_http_origin();
    if ( $origin ) {
        // Requests from file:// and data: URLs send "Origin: null".
        if ( 'null' !== $origin ) {
            $origin = esc_url_raw( $origin );
        }
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Vary: Origin', false );
    } elseif ( ! headers_sent() && 'GET' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        header( 'Vary: Origin', false );
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Can anyone let me know what should i do in this case? How do i fix is or i just should let it be how it is done by wordpress.
thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

see

```
function cors(){


        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        } else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        } else {
            $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $allowed_domains = array(
            'http://localhost:4200',
            'https://x.ir',
            'https://www.x.ir',
        );


        if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        }

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
            die();
        }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Should i replace the code i have with this one?

Comment: Cause when i remove the code i sent here before, it shows this error 
The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.
The REST API call gave the following unexpected result: (500) <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "rest_send_cors_headers" not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\s3\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:305 Stack trace: #0

Comment: use it as  golbal filter